# Localized WinForm, load Resources.lang-LANG.resx at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a translated "Form1". After change the language in a ComboBox, it load only the *Form1.lang-LANG.resx* not the *Resources.lang-LANG.resx*, is it possible to load this one too?

Here the code:

```
private void metroComboBoxLanguageSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo cui;

        var cultureInfo = CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        var cultureName = cultureInfo.Name;

        try
        {
            switch (metroComboBoxLanguageSelector.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                case "English":
                    cui = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                    SetCultureInfo(this, cui);
                    break;

                case "Deutsch":
                    cui = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
                    SetCultureInfo(this, cui);
                    break;

                case "Polski":
                    cui = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
                    SetCultureInfo(this, cui);
                    break;

                default:
                    cui = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
                    SetCultureInfo(this, cui);
                    break;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ListLang();
        }
    }

private void SetCultureInfo(Control parent, CultureInfo cui)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            var resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof (MainForm));
            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, cui);

            if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                SetCultureInfo(c, cui);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ListItems()
    {
        var cultureInfo = CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        var nativeName = cultureInfo.Parent.NativeName;

        metroComboBoxLanguageSelector.Items.Add(nativeName + " (System)");
        metroComboBoxLanguageSelector.Items.Add("English");
        metroComboBoxLanguageSelector.Items.Add("Deutsch");
        metroComboBoxLanguageSelector.Items.Add("Polski");
        metroComboBoxLanguageSelector.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Is it possible to load all .resx with specified language at runtime or otherwise like *CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(value);*

The Settings for the ComboBox will be saved.

Thank you.